# How to view and modify protocols like HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: http, https, protocols

I do not intend to modify them, but I'm just curious how can I see their files in my Windows or even in `apache` or `nginx`, and if they are binary files, how can I view them?

If there's an standard path for protocol files (like config files are usually in `/etc/`), please help me the path.

Comment: Protocols aren't really 'files'. Are you curious what it looks like on the wire? The official source for HTTP is https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110. Think of a protocol as an 'agreement' that everyone decides on.

Comment: @Evert thanks, I saw RFC. Yes I'm curious about that. Also suppose I want to see the protocol and send a bug email. Things like done by Devs in GitHub, seeing the code and saying the bug and the updates code

Comment: Protocols aren't 'code'. They are more like a contract (like the RFC).

Comment: I understand this might be a learning exercise and you don't have an explicit goal in mind with this. If you're just curious how servers like nginx are built, you could check out their source: http://hg.nginx.org/nginx/ . If that's not it, try to clarify what you're hoping to accomplish.